# How do I make an UPDATE while joining tables on SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, join, sql-update

I tried :

```
UPDATE closure JOIN item ON ( item_id = id ) 
SET checked = 0 
WHERE ancestor_id = 1
```

And:

```
UPDATE closure, item 
SET checked = 0 
WHERE ancestor_id = 1 AND item_id = id
```

Both works with MySQL, but those give me a syntax error in SQLite.

How can I make this UPDATE / JOIN works with SQLite version 3.5.9 ?

Comment: This is already answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845718/sql-how-to-update-table-values-from-another-table-with-the-same-user-name

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You can't. SQLite [doesn't support JOINs in UPDATE statements](http://sqlite.org/lang_update.html).

But, you can probably do this with a subquery instead:

```
UPDATE closure SET checked = 0 
WHERE item_id IN (SELECT id FROM item WHERE ancestor_id = 1);
```

Or something like that; it's not clear exactly what your schema is.

Comment: Where this gets hairy is when what you need to do is copy a column from one table to another in order to reverse the direction of an association.  where in MySQL you might do something like, create the foos.bar_id column, then `update foos join bars on bars.foo_id = foos.id set foos.bar_id = bars.id`, then drop the bars.foo_id column... how could this be done in SQLite?  If anyone knows, I could sure use it.

Comment: @hoff2 Actually, this is probably the simplest way to do this.  In my case I didn't even need to WHERE EXISTS part: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3845931/847201

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [REPLACE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) then you can use selection with joins.
Like this:

```
REPLACE INTO closure 
 SELECT sel.col1,sel.col2,....,sel.checked --checked should correspond to column that you want to change
FROM (
 SELECT *,0 as checked FROM closure LEFT JOIN item ON (item_id = id) 
 WHERE ancestor_id = 1) sel
```