# Update table values from another table with the same user name

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, with a same column named `user_name`, saying `table_a`, `table_b`.

I want to, copy from `table_b`, `column_b_1`, `column_b2`, to `table_b1`, `column_a_1`, `column_a_2`, respectively, where the `user_name` is the same, how to do it in SQL statement?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

As long as you have suitable indexes in place this should work alright:

```
UPDATE table_a
SET
      column_a_1 = (SELECT table_b.column_b_1 
                            FROM table_b
                            WHERE table_b.user_name = table_a.user_name )
    , column_a_2 = (SELECT table_b.column_b_2
                            FROM table_b
                            WHERE table_b.user_name = table_a.user_name )
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM table_b
        WHERE table_b.user_name = table_a.user_name
    )
```

UPDATE in [sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) did not support a FROM clause for a long time, which made this a little more work than in other RDBMS. UPDATE FROM was implemented in SQLite 3.33 however (2020-08-14) as mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63079219/895245

If performance is not satisfactory, another option might be to build up new rows for table_a using a select and join with table_a into a temporary table.  Then delete the data from table_a and repopulate from the temporary.

Comment: I had to exclude the table_a part from the left hand side of the set argument, to get this to work.  Using the answer above, it looks like `column_a_1 = (SELECT table_b.column_b_1 FROM table_b WHERE table_b.user_name = table_a.user_name )`

Comment: This answer helps understand in more detail how to copy for answer posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql/17267423#17267423

Comment: How many times the join is performed here? just 3 times, or instead 3 times per row in table_a? (my SQL is rusty)

Comment: answering my own question, it is 3 times per row, see @Alejadro answer...

Comment: Hi, I'm a newbie to SQL. Why are so many WHERE causes necessary?

Comment: @Llamageddon Because UPDATE in sqlite3 doesn't support a FROM clause, but see below for a newer answer!

Comment: Suitable indexes really is key here

Comment: For some reason this is extremely slow for me. It seems much faster to create a temporary table inner joining on one column and then another one inner joining on the other.

Comment: WARNING: If both values are NULL this is not counted as them being equal in the condition!

Answer (score 32):

Starting from the sqlite version 3.15 the syntax for [UPDATE](https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html) admits a column-name-list
in the SET part so the query can be written as

```
UPDATE table_a
SET
    (column_a_1, column_a_2) = (SELECT table_b.column_b_1, table_b.column_b_2
                                FROM table_b
                                WHERE table_b.user_name = table_a.user_name )
```

which is not only shorter but also faster

the last "WHERE EXISTS" part

```
WHERE
    EXISTS (
       SELECT *
       FROM table_b
       WHERE table_b.user_name = table_a.user_name
   )
```

is actually not necessary

Answer (score 25):

It could be achieved using `UPDATE FROM` syntax:

```
UPDATE table_a
SET column_a_1 = table_b.column_b_1
   ,column_a_2 = table_b.column_b_2
FROM table_b
WHERE table_b.user_name = table_a.user_name;
```

Alternatively:

```
UPDATE table_a
SET (column_a_1, column_a_2) = (table_b.column_b_1, table_b.column_b_2)
FROM table_b
WHERE table_b.user_name = table_a.user_name;
```

> **[UPDATE FROM - SQLite version 3.33.0](https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html#upfrom)**
>
> The UPDATE-FROM idea is an extension to SQL that allows an UPDATE statement to be driven by other tables in the database. The "target" table is the specific table that is being updated. With UPDATE-FROM you can join the target table against other tables in the database in order to help compute which rows need updating and what the new values should be on those rows

Comment: The second variant was way faster than the first one. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There is an even much better solution to update one table from another table:

```
;WITH a AS
(
    SELECT
        song_id,
        artist_id
    FROM
        online_performance
)
UPDATE record_performance
SET
    op_song_id=(SELECT song_id FROM a),
    op_artist_id=(SELECT artist_id FROM a)

;
```

Comment: Since the above is looking up specific rows (record_id= 2347), one would have to write the above code 1000 times to update 1000 rows?

Comment: This seems promising, but it won't work when you need to join both tables on a common column (such as `user_name` in the original question). Instead, this will set all corresponding values in the table being updated to those of only one record in the source table. Tried listing the common column and adding a `WHERE` condition, but it did not work.

Comment: **UPDATE** Actually, my attempt was correct. I might've had an extra line in the query and it said *no error* for some reason, which confused me. The solution was indeed to add the required column to the first select, and then make all other selects refer to it e.g. `(SELECT song_id FROM a WHERE guid=record_performance.guid)`

Answer (score 0):

Update tbl1
Set field1 = values
field2 = values
Where primary key in tbl1 IN ( select tbl2.primary key in tbl1
From tbl2
Where tbl2.primary key in tbl1 =
values);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer was very slow for me, which is in contrast to the following:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 AS SELECT c_new AS c1, table_a.c2 AS c2 FROM table_b INNER JOIN table_a ON table_b.c=table_a.c1;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2 AS SELECT t1.c1 AS c1, c_new      AS c2 FROM table_b INNER JOIN t1      ON table_b.c=t1.c2;
```