# sqlite update (without join)

Tags: sql, sqlite

Pretty new to sqlite (and sql).  Trying to modify one table using another.

```
create table Person(Key1 INTEGER, Key2 INTEGER, Name, IsDead, PRIMARY KEY (Key1,Key2));
create table Zombie(Key1 INTEGER, Key2 INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (Key1,Key2));
```

I'd like to update IsDead column based on a list provided in Zombie.
SQLite apparently can't use join with an update.  Considering UPDATE or REPLACE statements.
Thank you in advance.

As per @Tyler Ferraro, below is the solution.

```
UPDATE Person
SET IsDead = 1
WHERE EXISTS
(
SELECT *
FROM Zombie
WHERE Person.Key1 = Zombie.Key1 and Person.Key2 = Zombie.Key2
);
```

Below works for a single key, but I don't know how to handle composite keys.

```
UPDATE Person
SET IsDead = 1
WHERE Key1
IN
(
SELECT Key1
FROM Zombie
);
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your update statement? What's not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update table values from another table with the same user name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845718/update-table-values-from-another-table-with-the-same-user-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find the answer you're looking for here: [Update table values from another table with the same user name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845718/sql-how-to-update-table-values-from-another-table-with-the-same-user-name)

If you've got the proper Primary Keys setup, which you do, then this should be fairly straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of **INSERT OR REPLACE INTO** statement.

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Table1 
    (col1,col2,col3)
select Col1,Col2,Col3
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.Col1 = t2.Col1
```

if you face any *duplicate records* while using the statement *create a unique index* on *one* or *more columns* based on your logic then the duplication problem won't come up.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxName ON Table1 (Col1,Col2)
```