# Update query uses same value for each row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite database, which needs to be updated.
Using the update statement this should be easy.

But things aren't going as planned:

This is the complete query:

```
UPDATE products_new SET name =   
(
  SELECT products_sap.title 
  FROM products_sap, products_new 
  WHERE products_sap.id_a = products_new.product_id
);
```

As part of my debugging scheme I'm trying out each (sub)query.

This query ( identical to the one used in the above update )
shows me the correct records:

```
SELECT products_sap.id, products_sap.title 
FROM products_sap, products_new 
WHERE products_sap.id_a = products_new.product_id;
```

Example:

```
id | title
----------------------
 1 | Lorum Ipsum
 2 | Lorum Not Ipsum
 3 | Ipsum Lorum
```

**But**: all my rows in the updated table have identical `name` values * gasps *.

```
SELECT products_new.name from products_new;
```

Example:

```
id | name
----------------------
 1 | Lorum Ipsum
 2 | Lorum Ipsum
 3 | Lorum Ipsum
```

So my question is: 
how can I updated each row with it's relevant `name` value?

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845718/sql-how-to-update-table-values-from-another-table-with-the-same-user-name

Comment: Thanks @xQbert.  I did see that answer, but did not see the problem in my code.  Staring at the problem too long got to me I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because the `products_new` table in the inner query is *hiding* the `products_new` table in the `UPDATE` clause. Thus, you never actually join the rows from the table you are updating.

You need to make sure that for each row you are trying to update, its id (`product_id`) is joined with the table (`products_sap`) that contains the new value:

```
UPDATE products_new x 
SET name = (SELECT products_sap.title 
            FROM products_sap 
            WHERE products_sap.id_a = x.product_id);
```

Comment: Thanks - it's working now.

I removed the `products_new` from the inner query:
`from products_sap, products_new` is now `from products_sap`
in my inner query.

You do have a little typo in your answer: remove the `x` right after the `update products_new`.

Comment: It is actually an alias for the table, so that you can reference it in the inner query with just `x` instead of `products_new`.

Comment: Right.  I think it's time for bed : )
Thanks @joão.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely familiar with SQLite, but you can do something like the following in other dialects:

```
UPDATE products_new SET name = products_sap.title
   FROM products_new 
   INNER JOIN  products_sap 
   ON products_new.product_id = products_sap.id_a
```