# SQLite - Update field if new value isn't empty

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express

I'm making a little web interface with nodejs, express and sqlite3. There's a table with a fixed number of rows and columns, which can be updated through a form. The user isn't required to fill out all of the fields, so there's a lot of empty values in the post request. I only want to write back the the populated fields to the database and ignore the empty ones. I can think of a number of ugly and tedious ways to achieve this, but I'm sure there's some really simple solution I don't know of.

```
app.post('/updatevals', (req, res) => {

        for (const m in req.body) {

            const val = req.body[m]; // val = ['value1', '', '', 5]
                                     // user left index 1 + 2 empty
                                     // last value is primary key

            // Overwrites val2 + val3 with empty strings...
            const sql = "UPDATE mytable SET val1=?, val2=?, val3=? WHERE id=?"; 

            db.run(sql, val, (err) => {});

        }

});
```

Comment: Curious about some of your "ugly and tedious ways" to do it.

Comment: val itself won't be empty, but the array values inside of it may be empty strings.
I could do a separate query for each of the columns and put them in conditionals -> pretty ugly and tedious

Comment: You could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9814128/5156280).

Comment: Yes, I've already seen this post, but the tedious thing about it is that I'd have to apply this case/then/when/else construct to every single field..

Comment: To eliminate the tedious case/then/when/else construct, iterate val and replace `''` with `null` before sql is executed. Then it is the less tedious `val1 = COALESCE(?,val1)`.