# sqlite3 Error: datatype mismatch on complex update operation

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, sqldatatypes

I have two tables `auth_user` and `temp`

These are their schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "auth_user" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "username" varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "first_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "last_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "email" varchar(75) NOT NULL,
    "password" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    "is_staff" bool NOT NULL,
    "is_active" bool NOT NULL,
    "is_superuser" bool NOT NULL,
    "last_login" datetime NOT NULL,
    "date_joined" datetime NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "temp" ( "id" integer, "username" varchar(30));
```

I want the `id` fields in the `auth_user` table to be updated to the `id` field of the `temp` table provided the username is the same. How can I achieve this?

I tried this SQL:

```
Update auth_user set id=(select temp.id from temp where temp.username=auth_user.username);
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: datatype mismatch
```

Comment: could you provide the sample data you used because i can't duplicate the error.

Comment: Oh I didn't provide because it has sensitive information. Anyways I found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this question [Update table values from another table with the same user name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845718/sql-how-to-update-table-values-from-another-table-with-the-same-user-name)

It is similar to my question. Looking at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3845931/883832) in that page, I tried this query

```
update auth_user set id=(select temp.id from temp where temp.username=auth_user.username) where exists (select * from temp where temp.username=auth_user.username);
```

and it works great. Same as my query in the question but with just an extra `where` clause. I don't get the `Error: datatype mismatch` now (but I don't know the exact reason why).

Comment: looks like your inner query is returning a null value.