# Update on join in Sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two two tables `A` and `B` in which both `P` columns are common and I need to use `update` command in `table B` only when both `p` values are same and `C column from table A` is given

What I am trying is:

```
update B 
set P =100 
where B.P=A.P 
    and A.C=60
```

But it's giving me error no such column `A.P`

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql: how to update table values from another table with the same user name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845718/sql-how-to-update-table-values-from-another-table-with-the-same-user-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are updating table B and do not have reference to table A, so sqlite just does not know where to look for. Try this:

```
UPDATE B
SET    P = 100
WHERE  B.P IN (SELECT A.P
               FROM   A
               WHERE  A.C = 60)
```

Comment: Is this giving you output?
`SELECT * FROM B WHERE  B.P IN (SELECT A.P  FROM   A WHERE  A.C = 60)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
Update B set P = 100 WHERE B.P = (Select P from A WHERE C = 60)
```