# Update value in one table with result from another

Tags: mysql, sql

OK I have 2 tables:

```
holdings: (id, long_name, value, date, sedol)
asset_key: (id, long_name, sedol)
```

My issue is that in `holdings` there are many records where the `sedol` wasn't filled in. I have the `asset_key` table however that maps a given `long_name` to a `sedol`.

Is there a query that can populate `holdings.sedol` with the result from `asset_key`?

Something like:

```
UPDATE holdings SET holdings.sedol = 
    SELECT asset_key.sedol FROM asset_key 
    WHERE sedol.long_name = asset_key.long_name
```

Comment: You need multiple table syntax - see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3845931/2556111

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
UPDATE 
  holdings 
    LEFT JOIN asset_key ON sedol.long_name = asset_key.long_name 
SET 
  holdings.sedol=asset_key.sedol
```

Comment: It should be **`inner join`**

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
UPDATE `holdings`
SET `holdings`.`sedol` = (SELECT `asset_key`.`sedol`
                          FROM   `asset_key`
                          WHERE  `asset_key`.`long_name` = `holdings`.`long_name`)
```

However, if I am not wrong, you should be sure that this `SELECT` subquery returns only one row or MySQL will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Query:

```
update holdings 
SET holdings.sedol = asset_key.sedol
from holdings
inner join  asset_key on sedol.long_name = asset_key.long_name
```

> Note: The inner join should result in single value only

Comment: This is the SQL-Server `UPDATE..FROM` syntax. It won't work in MySQL.