# Python SQL Lite update using select query

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

How to update a table column with a value from another table in sql lite on python.

example,

table1

```
id name value brand
1  n1   v1    -
2  n2   v2    -
```

table2

```
id brand
1  b1
```

i want to update the table1 brand = b1 for id=1

i am trying to do this

```
UPDATE table1 r join table2 p on r.id= p.id set r.brand=p.brand
```

but python throws an error on this statement execution

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "r": syntax error
```

Any solutions please

Comment: `UPDATE table1 SET table1.brand = (SELECT table2.brand FROM table2 WHERE table2.id = table1.id)`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845718/sql-how-to-update-table-values-from-another-table-with-the-same-user-name

Comment: It doesnt work . sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to remove the `.` from the left-hand side of the `SET` clause:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET brand = (
        SELECT table2.brand FROM table2 WHERE table2.id = table1.id
    );
```

P.S. Nothing about this question seems Python-specific, so I suggest removing the Python tag.

Comment: I tried this in Python sql lite, so I thought it would be be meaningful

Comment: @Saravana, Not a problem; you didn't know the issue wasn't something related to the `sqlite` Python module. Did this solve the issue for you? If so, please accept the answer.

Comment: Will try this and let know . Thanks for the tip