# SQL Copy Data from one table to another during migration

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

I'm trying to move data from one table to another during a migration while adding the new columns. My user model had the column phone, and phone_permission, which I'd like to move to the gallery model (including its data). My code:

```
def self.up
  add_column :galleries, :phone, :string
  add_column :galleries, :phone_permission, :integer, default: 1

  execute "UPDATE galleries AS g, users AS u SET g.phone = u.phone WHERE u.id = g.user_id"
  execute "UPDATE galleries AS g, users AS u SET g.phone_permission = u.phone_permission WHERE u.id = g.user_id"

  remove_column :users, :phone
  remove_column :users, :phone_permission
end
```

Error: SQLite3::SQLException: near "AS": syntax error: UPDATE galleries AS g, users AS u SET g.phone = u.phone WHERE u.id = g.user_id

Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql: how to update table values from another table with the same user name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845718/sql-how-to-update-table-values-from-another-table-with-the-same-user-name)

Comment: Thanks @HannoBinder - Will take a closer look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code above is not valid SQL for SQLite.

Also, why not do it using ActiveRecord? Something like this should do the trick:

```
Gallery.joins(:user).update_all('galleries.phone = users.phone')
Gallery.joins(:user).update_all('galleries.phone_permission = users.phone_permission')
```

EDIT: As [the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) states for `update_all`

> This method constructs a single SQL UPDATE statement and sends it straight to the database. It does not instantiate the involved models and it does not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations.

This is just a prettier way to write Raw SQL in my opinion.

EDIT 2: As @llya pointed out in the comments, your migration would break if you were to change your model name. A simple trick here is to add this class definition on top of the migration:

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base; end
```

Comment: it is a bad idea to use models in migrations.

Comment: I would agree with you on that 95% of the time, the 5% being this `update_all` statement :). See my edit above.

Comment: If you'll edit this model name in future, your migration will unexecutable.

Comment: @llya, you're right, I will clarify this issue in another edit. Thanks