# Multi table join with SQLite UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

Using `SQLite 3`, I'm trying to update a column value from one table with a column value from another. This is very simple to achieve with `TSQL` but proving very difficult using `SQLite` which doesn't allow multi-table joins in the `UPDATE` clause.

[This other stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845718/update-table-values-from-another-table-with-the-same-user-name/3845931#3845931) appears to have the solution but it's not working for me in the sense that all my column values end up the same.

In my scenario I have 2 tables, `tbl_orders` and `tbl_orderitems`, where there can be many `tbl_orderitems` records for a given `tbl_orders` record.

I wish to update the `order_id` column in the `tbl_orderitems` table with the corresponding `id` value from the `tbl_orders` table.  Both tables have a common `order_number` column which links the `tbl_orderitems` records to a corresponding `tbl_orders` record.

Based on the [The answer to the question referred to above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845718/update-table-values-from-another-table-with-the-same-user-name/3845931#3845931) I have the following `SQL` statement.

```
UPDATE tbl_orderitems 
 SET order_id=(select tbl_orders.id from tbl_orders, tbl_orderitems where tbl_orders.order_number = tbl_orderitems.order_number)
 where  EXISTS (
        select tbl_orders.order_number from tbl_orders, tbl_orderitems where tbl_orders.order_number = tbl_orderitems.order_number 
 )
```

Unfortunately the `SQL` statement above ends up with all the `order_id`'s in the `tbl_orderitems` table being set to the same value, which of course is not what I want.

Is there a way to achieve what I want in `SQLite`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want correlated subqueries:

```
update tbl_orderitems 
    set order_id = (select o.id from tbl_orders o where o.order_number = tbl_orderitems.order_number)
    where exists (select 1
                  from tbl_orders o
                  where o.order_number = tbl_orderitems.order_number 
                 ) ;
```

Your problem is that you have `tbl_orderitems` in the subquery.  You need to refer to the outer query.  A secondary issue is the use of `,` in the `from` clause.  You should always use proper, explicit `join` syntax -- when appropriate, and in this case, it is not appropriate.

Comment: As it turns out the statement is actually even simpler. `UPDATE tbl_orderitems SET order_id=(select id from tbl_orders where tbl_orders.order_number = tbl_orderitems.order_number);` also works.

Comment: @SimonLomax . . . That will set the value even when no orders match `orderitems`.  That may be what you want, or all orders might match.