# Correlated subquery (or equivalent) in an SQLite UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql, triggers, sqlite

I have an SQLite3 database which, in order to optimize performance, uses computed columns kept up to date by triggers.

I'm now trying to add a trigger which would be analogous to this (untested but probably valid) SQLAlchemy ORM code

```
story.read_free = any(link.link_type.read_free for link in story.links)
```

...but I'm having trouble figuring out how to express that as an `UPDATE` clause. Here's what I've got so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS update_link_type AFTER UPDATE ON link_types
  FOR EACH ROW WHEN old.read_free <> new.read_free BEGIN
    UPDATE stories SET
      read_free = CASE WHEN (
        SELECT 1 FROM links as l, link_types as lt WHERE lt.id = new.id AND l.link_type_id = lt.id AND l.story_id = stories.id
      ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    WHERE id = (SELECT story_id from links as l, link_types as lt WHERE  l.link_type_id = lt.id AND lt.id = new.id)
  ;
END;
```

My specific problem is that I can't figure out how to ensure that the subquery in the `CASE` is correlated.

Either SQLite rejects the syntax (things like `UPDATE foo AS bar` and `UPDATE INNER JOIN ...` which are apparently how you do it on other DBs) or, as in the example I gave, it's valid, but has the wrong meaning. (In this case, "Set read_free on this story if there exists any link type with read_free, whether or not the story has links of that type)

If a more clean, concise phrasing of that `UPDATE` exists beyond simply fixing the problem, I'd also appreciate knowing it. Even if that did work, it'd be a very ugly solution compared to the worst of the rest of my triggers.

Comment: What is the schema of the link_types table, and what does the update query look like? Also, which columns are computed?

Comment: The update (aside from not working in its current form) is the large code block in my question. I'm not really sure `link_type`'s schema matters beyond it having a `read_free` column and a primary key named `id` that's referenced by `links`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While composing the `INSERT OR REPLACE` Robie suggested (Using the `REPLACE` alias to simplify any potential future port to MySQL), I realized that my mind had been stuck in a rut, making wrong assumptions and overcomplicating the problem. (Probably started working on it while sleep deprived and then never questioned my initial conclusions)

I was then able to reformulate my `UPDATE` to require only a single `JOIN` (also [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773441/how-do-i-make-an-update-while-joining-tables-on-sqlite) by SQLite) and then rewrite that as a `WHERE` subquery.

Here's the final trigger that resulted:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS update_link_type AFTER UPDATE ON link_types
FOR EACH ROW WHEN old.read_free <> new.read_free BEGIN
    UPDATE stories SET read_free = new.read_free
        WHERE id IN (SELECT story_id FROM links WHERE link_type_id = new.id)
    ;
END;
```

Much cleaner and much more maintainable.

I'm awarding the bounty to Robie for two reasons: First, because I'd have never come up with this answer without him jogging me out of that rut. Second, because if my requirements were as I'd originally believed, his answer *would* be the best.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an `UPDATE`, could you use a `INSERT OR REPLACE` instead? Unlike `UPDATE`, `INSERT OR REPLACE` will accept an embedded `SELECT`, so you could do the `UPDATE foo AS bar` or `UPDATE INNER JOIN` style thing. Your `SELECT` would just happen to produce duplicates of the rows in `stories` with just the columns you need changed.

Comment: Probably not. I'm a big believer in using CHECK constraints and foreign key constraints liberally to prevent duplication. In fact, to ensure that I could, I actually patched the CakePHP SQLite3 data source to emit `PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON` on opening a connection. However, I will think about whether a second table with a schema like `(story_id, read_free)`, a `JOIN` that's always done, a covering index, and `OR REPLACE` would work.

Comment: I'm not suggesting changing the schema, or actually producing duplicate data. I'm just suggesting using `INSERT OR REPLACE` as a drop-in replacement for `UPDATE` in this particular query. Your database will stay normalised except for the computed columns you already have. When I say duplicates of rows, I mean that the `INSERT OR REPLACE` will effectively always be a `REPLACE` because you've engineered the query to do this, and the embedded `SELECT` will match the existing data, so it will behave the same as the `UPDATE` that you want.

Comment: Ahh, point. Give me a bit to experiment with a subquery to preserve/regenerate the three existing computed columns (computed against a different table) and I'll let you know how it turns out.