# SQLite: JOIN back INTO left table?

Tags: sqlite

If I have this statement,

```
SELECT table1.*, table2_1.`values` AS val_1 
FROM table1 JOIN table2_1 
ON table1.row_names=table2_1.row_names
```

I would actually like this the result joined back into `table1`. Any inclusion of a join statement after `SELECT` and before `FROM` gives me an error.

Why can I not save the results to a table, and is it possible to save it back to one of the original tables?

Comment: Ah, apparently SQLite does not support `INTO` statements. But `CREATE TABLE {tablename} AS SELECT {rest}` works.

Answer (score 1):

Because you do it the wrong way. [`SELECT`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) statement will not modify you data no matter how much you want it. If you want to modify data, you need to use [`UPDATE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) statement.

Comment: But how can I effectively combine an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` statement in SQLite? There is an [example using a subquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773441/how-do-i-make-an-update-while-joining-tables-on-sqlite) but the implementation is for a specific and simpler case.

Comment: As you can see from referenced by you question, SQLite doesn't support `JOIN`s in `UPDATE`. You have to perform each update manually, i.e. iterate thru `table2_1` and for each row, perform `UPDATE` in `table1`.