# How to run an SQL UPDATE query where a field is modified and then used

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

Is the following posible on SQL? (Using SQLITE3)

```
UPDATE Table SET
Value1 = (SELECT ...)
Value2 = Value3/Value1; # The new value1!!! Not the value currently on the DB
```

Right now I need to do something like:

```
UPDATE Table SET
Value1 = (SELECT ...)
Value2 = Value3/(SELECT ...);
```

This makes the code quite long. Imagine it is not only Value1 I am updating but other fields too.

So the only solution I found is to do 2 UPDATES. First:

```
UPDATE Table SET
Value1 = (SELECT ...);
```

And then

```
UPDATE Table SET
Value2 = Value3/Value1;
```

Anyone with a more "beautiful" way of doing this?

Thanks,

Comment: I would consider doing the inner `SELECT` first, then `UPDATE` the two Values in one statement.

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite 3.8.3 or later, you can use a [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
WITH u(v) AS (
    SELECT ...
)
UPDATE MyTable
SET Value1 = (SELECT v FROM u),
    Value2 = Value3 / (SELECT v FROM u);
```

(This even works with correlated subqueries.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `replace`

```
replace into table2
(Value1 , Value2)
select src.Value1 , src.Value3 / src.Value1
from table1 src
```

In sql you cant do `UDPATE ... FROM` as explain in this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790595/sqlite-inner-join-update-using-values-from-another-table)**

Comment: This will delete any old rows, so the values in the other columns will be lost.

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this :

```
update Table1 set szNo = KO.nNo 
from 
(select nNo From Table2) KO
```

Comment: I dont think you can do that in sqllite