# update table data in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have to Tables sale and stock

sale

```
   idStock  
    1000
    1000
    1001
    1002
    1002
    1003
```

stock

```
idStock   sold
1000        0 
1001        0 
1002        0 
1003        0
```

how to update stock table like this (count total sale items and update the sold column in stock)

```
idStock   sold
1000        2 
1001        1 
1002        2
1003        1
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Generally we provide greater assistance to those who show what they themselves have tried and failed with.  We don't want to code it for you, we want to help you code it and learn!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790595/sqlite-inner-join-update-using-values-from-another-table for some guideance

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE stock
SET stock.sold = sale_1.myCount
FROM (SELECT idStock, count(*) as myCount
      FROM sale
      GROUP BY idStock) as sale_1
INNER JOIN stock on sale_1.idStock = stock.idStock
```

I'm doing this from memory. I hope it works. Let us know.

Comment: UPDATE…FROM is not valid SQL.

Comment: Sorry sir.

UPDATE stock SET stock.sold = (SELECT myCount FROM (SELECT idStock, count(*) as myCount FROM sale GROUP BY idStock) as x WHERE stock.idStock = x.idStock)

Follow this example:
UPDATE tbl1 SET col2 = (SELECT col2 FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2.col1 = tbl1.col1)


Again from my head. I hope you can sort the errors