# sqlite: update column from join

Tags: pandas, sqlite, join, sql-update

I've tried with the answers below, but I cannot find a proper way of doing this

1. [SQLite inner join - update using values from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790595/sqlite-inner-join-update-using-values-from-another-table)
2. [How do I make an UPDATE while joining tables on SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773441/how-do-i-make-an-update-while-joining-tables-on-sqlite)
3. [Update table values from another table with the same user name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845718/update-table-values-from-another-table-with-the-same-user-name)

Here's the problem. I have a sqlite db with two tables. In the code below I use pandas to insert some dummy values

```
import sqlite3
import pandas

conn = sqlite3.connect('foo.db')
curs = conn.cursor()

df1 = pandas.DataFrame([{'A' : 1, 'B' : 'a', 'C' : None}, {'A' : 1, 'B' : 'b', 'C' : None}, {'A' : 2, 'B' : 'c', 'C' : None}])
df1.to_sql('table1', conn, index = False)

df2 = pandas.DataFrame([{'A' : 1, 'D' : 'x'}, {'A' : 2, 'D' : 'y'}])
df2.to_sql('table2', conn, index = False)
```

This results in two tables

```
pandas.read_sql('select * from table1', conn)
   A  B     C
0  1  a  None
1  1  b  None
2  2  c  None
```

and

```
pandas.read_sql('select * from table2', conn)
   A  D
0  1  x
1  2  y
```

Now I want to join these two tables on column `A` and update columns `table1.C` with the resulting `D`

This is what I've tried

> Solution 1 in the list above

```
sql = """
    replace into table1 (C)    
    select table2.D
    from table2
    inner join table1 on table1.A = table2.A
"""
curs.executescript(sql)
conn.commit()
pandas.read_sql('select * from table1', conn)
     A     B     C
0  1.0     a  None
1  1.0     b  None
2  2.0     c  None
3  NaN  None     x
4  NaN  None     x
5  NaN  None     y
```

wrong

> Solution 2 in the list above

```
sql = """
    replace into table1 (C)
    select sel.D from (
    select table2.D as D
    from table2
    inner join table1 on table1.A = table2.A
    ) sel
"""
curs.executescript(sql)
conn.commit()
pandas.read_sql('select * from table1', conn)
     A     B     C
0  1.0     a  None
1  1.0     b  None
2  2.0     c  None
3  NaN  None     x
4  NaN  None     x
5  NaN  None     y
```

> Solution 3 in the list above

```
sql = """
    update table1 
    set C = (
    select table2.D
    from table2
    inner join table1 on table1.A = table2.A
    )
"""
curs.executescript(sql)
conn.commit()

pandas.read_sql('select * from table1', conn)
   A  B  C
0  1  a  x
1  1  b  x
2  2  c  x
```

which is clearly wrong since the last row is updated to `x`, it should be `y`

At this point I'm pretty much out of options. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot quite remember (or explain intelligently) why solution 3 doesn't work but I think it's something like `table1` in the subquery is not the "same" `table1` being updated. (I have struggled with this in the past, and have developed habits to avoid it, no longer remember the reason).

I do know if you change
 `inner join table1 on table1.A = table2.A` to 
 `where table1.A = table2.A` it will work.

This will also work:

```
update table1 
    set C = (
    select table2.D
    from table2
    inner join table1 t1 on t1.A = table2.A
    and t1.A = table1.A
    )
```

Both of these solutions will set C to null if there is no matching row in table2.

Answer (score 5):

I think the correct way would be to use the `UPDATE-FROM` syntax introduced by [sqlite version 3.33](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_33_0.html) (was not available at the time this question was asked):

```
UPDATE table1 AS dst
    SET C=src.D
    FROM table2 AS src
    WHERE dst.A=src.A
```