# How to update rows of one table with values from another table based on common parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a 2 tables.

```
Table A with the following columns
Id  title  desc  type  


Table B with the following columns
Id   type
```

I want to basically  update all the rows of Table A in which I would replace the type with the Id value of Table B that has the corresponding same type.

For example

```
Table A can have
1 ,test1 ,ddd, play
2 ,test2 ,ddd2, go
3 ,test3 ,ddd3, play


Table B has
1, play
2, go
```

So I want to be able to run the query so Table A looks like

```
1 ,test1 ,ddd, 1
2 ,test2 ,ddd2, 2
3 ,test3 ,ddd3, 1
```

How can this be achieved in "SqlLite" query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make an UPDATE while joining tables on SQLite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773441/how-do-i-make-an-update-while-joining-tables-on-sqlite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE tableA tA
JOIN tableB tB
ON tA.type = tB.type
SET tA.type = tB.Id
```

Comment: I keep getting "error near tA", Could it be that SQLITE is diff from MYSQL? I am using SQL lite

Comment: I did a search and it seems SQLite does not support Join in update. I hope I am wrong

Comment: Apparently SQLite allows correlated subqueries. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773441/how-do-i-make-an-update-while-joining-tables-on-sqlite

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:mysql], so  i gave that answer. I don't know sqlite.