# Sqlite: I need to update a data from one table to another

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables in my sqlite database, with a column name as in both tables solution, solutionimage, id saying tableA and tableB. I want to, copy from tableB solution, solutionimage  to tableA matching the id in both table respectively, how to do it?

I have google it and tried but i didnt get it..  Any one help me. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: With over 100 posts on SO you can sure do better. Please add more detail to your question.

Comment: Clarify your question it is not clear at all what you are doing; question title is saying `ADD data` but phrasing of your question could imply you actually want to update entries in tableB with values from tableA? What is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideally you would want to join the table you are updating to the other table where you take the values from.

But I just read that `JOINS` in `UPDATES` are [not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/774300/2186023) in `SQLITE` so subqueries are the way to go I suppose:

```
UPDATE tableB
    SET
      Solution = (SELECT Solution FROM tableA WHERE ID = tableB.ID),
      SolutionImage = (SELECT Solution FROM tableA WHERE ID = tableB.ID);
```

See this [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/7bf7c/2) for example output.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I have done a mistake.. i have enter it in WHERE ID = ID  This is my mistake i have changed into like your query its worked fine....Thanksss....