# conditional UPDATE sqlite statement

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am working on sqlite 1st time  
I have need help on following problem  
I have 2 tables as follows

## test1

---

key value
a    1  
b    2  
c    3  
e    7  
f    41  
j    52

## test2

---

key value  
a    null  
b    null  
c    null  
d    null  
e    null  
f    null  
g    null  
j    null

I am trying to updating values of test2 if key in table test2 = test1 then update value or else put null

expected output is like this

## test2

---

key value  
a    1  
b    2  
c    3  
d    null  
e    7  
f    41  
g    null  
j    52

I try this query

insert into test2([value])
select test1.value  
from test1, test2  
where test2.value= test1.value;

but it not working  
how to solve this?

Comment: You don't have to use HTML to format your question. Code snippets can be indented using four spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Assuming you mean conditional UPDATE, not INSERT)*

Fortuitously, it seems you need to reset `test2` to null where the join fails, so you can do an update with the set specified as a subquery:

```
update test2
set value = 
(SELECT t1.value
 FROM test1 t1 where t1.key = test2.key
 LIMIT 1);
```

[SqlFiddle:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/19653/9)

The `LIMIT` will ensure just one row returned, but if the relationship between test1 and test2 isn't 1:1 you will need to apply logic to determine how to join the two tables.

Comment: hey thanks for answering, but there is problem it fills table test2 all rows with 1st match values not putting null. and you are right i am asking for conditional updating not insert :)

Comment: ? I can't repeat as per the SqlFiddle. What you might do is explicitly alias the inner test table (t1) - this will make it easier to identity which column belongs to which table. I've also updated the fiddle with a variant which will retain the original value (i.e. it won't overwrite with null if there is no match). I wasn't quite sure what you wanted in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not know sqllite syntax but should be like this. Because your test2 table already have null value so only you have to update value column where key value matched with test1 table

**MSSQL:-**

```
UPDATE R 
SET R.[value] = p.[value]
FROM dbo.test2 AS R
INNER JOIN dbo.test1 AS P 
       ON R.[key] = P.[key]
```

I just follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773441/how-do-i-make-an-update-while-joining-tables-on-sqlite) then I see that sql lite does not support join in update statement, but you can use in sub query

**SQLLITE**

```
UPDATE test2 SET [value] = ( 
             SELECT [value] FROM test1 WHERE test1.key = test2.key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

UPDATE test2 
  SET    value = (SELECT test1.value 
                          FROM   test1 
                          WHERE  test2.key =test1.key) ;