# Update with two table ,I had a example for one row,but I must update 168432 rows,used sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, spatialite

I want to update the sqlite table, the following is the example for updating one row:

```
update tpecroad set tnode = (SELECT  b.nodeid FROM "TPECRoad" as a
join tpecnode as b 
where pointn(a.geometry,numpoints(a.geometry)) = b.geometry and a.pk =1)
where pk=1
```

but there are 168432 rows to be updated, is there any faster way to update the large amount of the data?

It's like changed a.pk=1~168432 and pk=1~168432

Thanks a lots!!

Comment: Are you saying you want to update records where pk is between 1 and 168432 i.e all the records? If so just remove both instances of pk = 1

Comment: I meant That ,The stupid function is make 168432 querys ,and only changed the (a.pk =2 pk=2).. 3.4.5...

Comment: What code are you actually using to try update all the records?

Comment: update tpecroad set tnode = (SELECT  b.nodeid FROM "TPECRoad" as a
join tpecnode as b 
where pointn(a.geometry,numpoints(a.geometry)) = b.geometry )  
//but all rows data are same

Answer (score 0):

```
update tpecroad as c
set tnode = ( SELECT  b.nodeid 
              FROM "TPECRoad" as a join tpecnode as b 
              where pointn(a.geometry,numpoints(a.geometry)) = b.geometry and a.pk = c.pk);
```

Comment: Insert 'as' in query about, could you check it again?

Comment: It got a same error , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773441/how-do-i-make-an-update-while-joining-tables-on-sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Update tpecroad a
set tnode = (SELECT b.nodeid 
FROM tpecnode as b 
where pointn(tpecroad.geometry,numpoints(tpecroad.geometry)) = b.geometry)
```

Comment: It was running but the table's contents wasn't the answer.I thought the query in the brackets can't touched outside like tpecroad.

Comment: @user3513254 I've updated my answer, I hadn't realized this was sqlite

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right, this query may help:

```
update tpecroad a set tnode = (
    select b.nodeid from tpecnode b
    where pointn(a.geometry,numpoints(a.geometry)) = b.geometry
)
where exists (
    select 1 from tpecnode b
    where pointn(a.geometry,numpoints(a.geometry)) = b.geometry
);
```

Edit: If a.pk = b.pk must verify to perform the update, the query will look as follows:

```
update tpecroad a set tnode = (
    select b.nodeid from tpecnode b
    where pointn(a.geometry,numpoints(a.geometry)) = b.geometry
        and a.pk = b.pk
)
where exists (
    select 1 from tpecnode b
    where pointn(a.geometry,numpoints(a.geometry)) = b.geometry
        and a.pk = b.pk
);
```

Comment: But the problem was .The sqlite can't used 
"update tpecroad a set tnode" and "update tpecroad as a set tnode"