# Why am I getting an error in executing this statement in DB Browser for SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, t-sql

I am trying to execute this statement in DB Browser:

```
UPDATE p SET SourceId = s.Id 
FROM Practice p INNER JOIN Source s ON  p.Source = s.Name
```

And it is refusing to execute complaining that says:

> there is a syntax error near "FROM"

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 How are those answers different from my t-sql

Comment: [SQLite doesn't support JOINs in UPDATE statements](http://sqlite.org/lang%5Fupdate.html), Use [IN statement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/774300/4519059) ;).

Comment: Coming to this in 2022: it seems there's a bug in DB Browser for SQLite where queries break if you break the SQL up over multiple lines. Very annoying.

Answer (score -1):

you need to replace `Source` by `[Source]`

Answer (score -1):

Source is a keyword in SQL used for MERGE JOINs.

Put brackets around it to force it to be used as a string literal:

```
UPDATE p 
SET SourceId = s.Id 
FROM Practice p 
INNER JOIN [Source] s 
ON p.[Source] = s.[Name]
```

Comment: No joy.  Error remains.  But good info that I did not know