# SQLite inserting a select into a column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would need help with a following case:

I have a table called Prevodnik with these columns:

```
Chaincode | Shopcode  
2225 | XX2250  
5552 | XX5548
```

Then there is a table called Prevodnik2 with following:

```
Chaincode | Shopcode  
2225 |   
5552 |
```

I need to join the shopcode records into the empty column Shopcode, but I can't make it work. So far I've tried something similar to this:

update prevodnik2 set shopcode = `(select prevodnik.shopcode from prevodnik LEFT JOIN prevodnik2 ON prevodnik2 = prevodnik.chaincode)`

Would you happen to know what to do with this, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773441/how-do-i-make-an-update-while-joining-tables-on-sqlite also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845718/sql-how-to-update-table-values-from-another-table-with-the-same-user-name

Comment: why two tables with the same content in the first place? Wrong design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery leads to multiple rows, but only one is needed in the `SET`-clause. You can try the following. I don't know if SQLLite supports everything in this statement.

```
update prevodnik2 p2 set shopcode = (select p.shopcode from prevodnik p WHERE p2.chaincode = p.chaincode)
```