# how to perform a correlated query operation in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to update an sqlite table with values taken from another table but conditional on matching value in a key field but cannot figure out how to do it.

In postgres I can use "correlated query" as below

```
drop table if exists zzzz_tab_1;
drop table if exists zzzz_tab_2;
drop table if exists zzzz_tab_3;

create table zzzz_tab_1 (nr int , x_names varchar(20));
create table zzzz_tab_2 (nr int , x_age int);
create table zzzz_tab_3 (nr int , x_names varchar(20), x_age int);

INSERT INTO zzzz_tab_1 (nr, x_names) VALUES (1, 'AB');
INSERT INTO zzzz_tab_1 (nr, x_names) VALUES (2, 'BA');
INSERT INTO zzzz_tab_1 (nr, x_names) VALUES (3, 'CD');

INSERT INTO zzzz_tab_2 (nr, x_age) VALUES (1, 10);
INSERT INTO zzzz_tab_2 (nr, x_age) VALUES (3, 20);

-- add values 

-- add nr from zzzz_tab_1
insert into zzzz_tab_3 (nr) select nr from zzzz_tab_1;
--adding names from zzzz_tab_1
update zzzz_tab_3 
set 
  x_names = t1.x_names 
  from (select nr, x_names from zzzz_tab_1) as t1 
  where zzzz_tab_3.nr = t1.nr;
--adding age from zzzz_tab_2
update zzzz_tab_3 
set 
  x_age = t1.x_age 
  from (select nr, x_age from zzzz_tab_2) as t1 
  where zzzz_tab_3.nr = t1.nr;

select * from zzzz_tab_3;
```

But this does not seem to work in sqlite. 
I tried the following code based on the reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773441/how-do-i-make-an-update-while-joining-tables-on-sqlite), but it does also not work.

```
with tx1
as
(select nr, x_names from zzzz_tab_1)
replace into 
zzzz_tab_3
select 
zzzz_tab_3.nr, zzzz_tab_3.x_names
from zzzz_tab_3
inner join tx1 on tx1.nr = zzzz_tab_3.nr
```

*Is this operation possible at all in sqlite ?*

**-- Clarification --**

Basically I have two tables zzzz_tab_1 and zzzz_tab_3

*zzzz_tab_1*

```
nr  x_names
1   AB
2   BA
3   CD
```

*zzzz_tab_3*

```
nr  x_names
1    null
2    null       
3   null
```

I want to add data from *zzzz_tab_1* to *zzzz_tab_3* 
based on the value of the field 
the result (zzzz_tab_3) should be

*zzzz_tab_3*

```
nr  x_names
1   AB  
2   BA  
3   CD
```

P.S: One can create a new table with join but my tables are quite big (30 Mio Records)

Comment: Describe what the problem is that you're trying to solve, and what the result should be.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is interested, a colleague proposed this approach (and it works).

```
 update zzzz_tab_3
 set
 x_names = (select x_names from zzzz_tab_1 where zzzz_tab_3.nr =   zzzz_tab_1.nr);



update zzzz_tab_3
set
x_age = (select x_age from zzzz_tab_2  where zzzz_tab_3.nr = 
zzzz_tab_2.nr);

-- verify 
select * from zzzz_tab_3;
```