# Cross table update join operation works in MySQL but not SQLite

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have this cross table update join operation in MySQL that works perfectly but when executed against SQLite it wouldn't work.

The error message given by SQLite was quite vague and I wasn't sure what's wrong or different between both SQLs that is causing the problem.

How can I get it working for SQLite?

**Query that works in MySQL:**

```
update
  `entries`
  inner join `transactions` on `entries`.`transaction_id` = `transactions`.`id`
  and `transactions`.`batch_id` = 4
  and `entries`.`number` = "2010"
set
  `entries`.`prize` = "consolation",
  `entries`.`winnings` = entries.amount * 500,
  `transactions`.`winnings` = transactions.winnings + (entries.amount * 500)
```

**Error message given by SQLite:**

```
Result: near "inner": syntax error
At line 1:
update
  `bets`
  inner
```

Comment: SQLite does not support joins in an UPDATE statement.

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html for sqlite's update syntax. That... isn't close to anything it understands.

Comment: Thanks. So that's why hmmm....

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773441/how-do-i-make-an-update-while-joining-tables-on-sqlite